# JS сортировка массива объектов по двум свойства

Tags: javascript, json, сортировка

Есть массив. Как отсортировать его по убыванию? Сначала по score, а потом по time

```
[
   {time: '20', score: '10'},
   {time: '33', score: '55'},
   {time: '51', score: '41'},
   {time: '10', score: '10'},
   {time: '20', score: '10'},
];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что я правильно понял. В примере сделал так: сортировка по score более приоритетна.

```js
var s = [
   {time: '20', score: '10'},
   {time: '33', score: '55'},
   {time: '51', score: '41'},
   {time: '10', score: '10'},
   {time: '20', score: '10'},
];
s.sort(function(x1,x2) {
  if (x1.score < x2.score) return -1;
  if (x1.score > x2.score) return 1;
  // при равных score сортируем по time
  if (x1.time < x2.time) return -1;
  if (x1.time > x2.time) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
```

Comment: А разве не наоборот? Раз `time` потом сортируется, затирая предыдущую сортировку, то он важнее.

Comment: Если у объектов различаются score, то до сравнения по time не доходит. Time сравниваются, если у объектов равны score. (В моем примере. Если нужно наоборот - просто поменяйте).